# 12296:26672:0420/163936.459:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238) XXX Init() Error in "Selenium Python"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit).
It was not happening before and the code was working completely fine.
But after few days I ran it again and this error came.

I am using these modules->

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import csv
import time
from tkinter import *

def Authorization():
    time.sleep(15)
    username = driver.find_element_by_id("userInput")
    username.send_keys('username')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login-button']").click()

    time.sleep(5)
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='passwordInput']")
    password.send_keys('password')

    submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='login-button']").click()

def Extractor():
    time.sleep(25)
    integrated_release = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='versionArea']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
    global integrated_release_data
    integrated_release_data = [x.text for x in integrated_release]

    impact_release = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='versionArea']/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")
    global impact_release_data 
    impact_release_data = [x.text for x in impact_release]

    build_platform = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='btkArea']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span")
    global build_platform_data 
    build_platform_data = [x.text for x in build_platform]


def To_csv():
    csvData = [final_data]
    with open('data.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
        writers = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writers.writerows(csvData)
    csvFile.close()

def printtext():
    global bugName
    bugName = e.get() 
    print(bugName)

def kinter():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x100")
    root.title('xtractor')

    var = StringVar()
    label = Label( root, textvariable=var)
    var.set("Enter")
    label.pack()

    global e
    e = Entry(root)
    e.pack()
    e.focus_set()

    b = Button(root,text='submit',command=printtext)
    b.pack(side='bottom')
    root.mainloop()

kinter()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

bugs = bugName.split(',')

driver.get("http........"+bugs[0])
bugname = [bugs[0]]

Authorization()
Extractor()
final_data = a+b+c+d+e
To_csv()

count = 0
for bug in bugs:
    try:
        if count == 0:
            count += 1
            continue

        driver.get("http:....."+bug)
        bugname = [bug]

        Extractor()
        final_data = a+b+c+d+e
        To_csv()
    except:
        continue
```

and I have installed the same version of webdriver as of chrome.
Any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please include the full exception message and stack trace with your question. You'll also need to include the code you wrote where the exception was thrown. Seeing the imports is good, but this doesn't look like an error that occurs when executing the import statements.

Comment: This is the only message that comes and hangs the code. The code I didn't want to because its not open. Although, I have changed the site as well as variable name. Thanks Greg for pointing it out.

Comment: Which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: As mentioned above, I am using Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Which version of ChromeDriver are you using?

Comment: I have the same issue using Chrome 81 and ChromeDriver 81.

Comment: Same version, 81 (chromedriver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
```

...implies that call to `on_init_` raised an error.

---

### Analysis

This error is defined in [bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/device/bluetooth/bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc) and was the direct impact of the changes incorporated within [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) as per the details available within the discussion [Chrome no longer accepts certificates that fallback to common name](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=700595)

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v84.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 84.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v84.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/84.0.4147.30/notes.txt))
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.

---

### Additional considerations

However it was observed that this error can be supressed by running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. but that would be a deviation from the documentation in [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/chrome-doesn-t-start) where it is mentioned:

> A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as root user (administrator) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing '--no-sandbox' flag when creating your [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) session, i.e. the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) session as such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged.

Ideally, you need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.

---

### Suppressing the error

Finally, as per the documentation in [Selenium Chrome Driver: Resolve Error Messages Regarding Registry Keys and Experimental Options](http://blogs.stevelongchen.com/2020/05/15/selenium-chrome-driver-resolve-error-messages-regarding-registry-keys-and-experimental-options/) these error logs can be supressed by adding the argument:

```
excludeSwitches: ['enable-logging']
```

So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Version 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit),too.
and the same happens i encounter
but it still run successfully.
and now i still find to solve this problem!

Comment: Even i am facing this weird issue, the code runs successfully but throws this bizarre error. Any solution you have found ?

Comment: No,If I find to solve i will tell you.but I was busy for my work,I will find to solve lately.And then if you find the way to solve,you will also tell me the way.thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem 
i tried alot but could not find the answer i needed 
the best thing i came up with to solve the error is to change your webdriver to [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and use [firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) instead of chrome

i hope this helped

Comment: sorry but the error is about chrome, and i have the same error since i switched to nodejs x64. this is a x64 related error.

Answer (score 0):

if you used chocolaty to install the webdriver it will install the latest one like beta of chrome-driver. so if your are in chrome browser version  81.x  you will get driver of 83.x as chrome 83 is in beta.so better to twice check.